# How to calculate sha256 hash using gpujs?

Tags: node.js, hash, cryptography, gpgpu

I'm trying to calculate sha256 hash of numbers using gpu.js. This is my code, I'm using builtin crypto module of nodejs.

```
const kernel = gpu.createKernel(function (num) {
  const hash = crypto.createHash("sha256");
  const hashed = hash.update((num + this.thread.x).toString());

  return hashed.digest("hex");
}, settings);
```

I'm getting this error.

```
/home/madhav/Documents/Web Development/REST Stuff/gpu-trial/node_modules/gpu.js/src/backend/function-node.js:972
    return new Error(`${error} on line ${ splitLines.length }, position ${ lineBefore.length }:\n ${ debugString }`);
           ^

Error: Markup type null not handled on line 5, position 1:
 const hash = crypto.createHash("sha256");
    at WebGLFunctionNode.astErrorOutput (/home/madhav/Documents/Web Development/REST Stuff/gpu-trial/node_modules/gpu.js/src/backend/function-node.js:972:12)
    at WebGLFunctionNode.astVariableDeclaration (/home/madhav/Documents/Web Development/REST Stuff/gpu-trial/node_modules/gpu.js/src/backend/web-gl/function-node.js:841:20)
    at WebGLFunctionNode.astGeneric (/home/madhav/Documents/Web Development/REST Stuff/gpu-trial/node_modules/gpu.js/src/backend/function-node.js:930:23)
    at WebGLFunctionNode.astFunction (/home/madhav/Documents/Web Development/REST Stuff/gpu-trial/node_modules/gpu.js/src/backend/web-gl/function-node.js:116:12)
    at WebGLFunctionNode.astFunctionExpression (/home/madhav/Documents/Web Development/REST Stuff/gpu-trial/node_modules/gpu.js/src/backend/function-node.js:1019:17)
    at WebGLFunctionNode.astGeneric (/home/madhav/Documents/Web Development/REST Stuff/gpu-trial/node_modules/gpu.js/src/backend/function-node.js:898:23)
    at WebGLFunctionNode.toString (/home/madhav/Documents/Web Development/REST Stuff/gpu-trial/node_modules/gpu.js/src/backend/function-node.js:324:32)
    at FunctionBuilder.getPrototypes (/home/madhav/Documents/Web Development/REST Stuff/gpu-trial/node_modules/gpu.js/src/backend/function-builder.js:328:21)
    at FunctionBuilder.getPrototypeString (/home/madhav/Documents/Web Development/REST Stuff/gpu-trial/node_modules/gpu.js/src/backend/function-builder.js:318:17)
    at HeadlessGLKernel.translateSource (/home/madhav/Documents/Web Development/REST Stuff/gpu-trial/node_modules/gpu.js/src/backend/web-gl/kernel.js:596:45)
```

I think this error is because gpujs does not support all legal js syntax. Is there any other way to calculate sha256 hash.

Comment: The gpujs-threads support only few data types and mathematical functions as described in the documentation. So you need an implementation of the SHA256 algorithm that uses only these limited types and functions, which is probably relatively elaborate.